# javax.faces.FacesException Unable to find CDI BeanManager

Tags: jsf, wildfly

I am using:

- **TARGET RUNTIME**:
- WildFly 14.0
- **DYNAMIC WEB MODULE VERSION**
- 4.0
- **CONFIGURATION**
- Dynamic Web Module 4.0
- Java               1.8
- JavaServer Faces   2.3
- **JSF CAPABILITIES**
- JSF Configuration File: /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
- JSF Servlet Name: Faces Servlet  JSF
- Servlet Class Name: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
- URL Mapping Patterns: *.jsf

I have this error:

> 21:26:14,941 SEVERE
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 76) Critical error during deployment: :
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory
>   'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured
>   properly.     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:357)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:443)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:237)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>     at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
>
> Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
>
> 21:26:14,945 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."PruebaTresWebJEE.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."PruebaTresWebJEE.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.

>

Comment: The BeanManager wasn't instantiated/resolved properly. Du you have a beans.xml in your project?

Comment: Title does not match the content. And does it work on wildfly 13 (WITH jsf 2.3 enabled?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this issue is resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607677/wildfly-starts-with-error-javax-faces-facesexception-unable-to-find-cdi-beanma), the solution is to add an xml file "beans.xml" in the WEB-INF directory with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```